# How can I make a SelectBox required in qooxdoo?

Tags: qooxdoo

How can I force a user to make a selection from a qooxdoo SelectBox? I would like the SelectBox to initially appear with an empty selection (or better yet, a "Please select..." message). I would like form validation to fail if the user has not made a selection, and the selectBox to appear with the red "invalid" decoration and "required" tooltip, just like a required textField.

Similarly for RadioButtonGroup: is there a way to make the group initially appear with no button selected, and not become valid until a selection is made?

---

Later... this seems to work for the SelectBox case:

```
var genderSlct = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
genderSlct.add(new qx.ui.form.ListItem("")); // initially selected null item
genderSlct.add(new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Male", null, "M"));
genderSlct.add(new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Female", null, "F"));
...

myForm.getValidationManager().setValidator(function(items) {
    var valid = true;

    if (genderSlct.getSelection()[0].getModel() == null) {
        genderSlct.setValid(valid = false);
        genderSlct.setInvalidMessage("Please select your gender.");
    }   
    ...   

    if (valid) {
        genderSlct.setValid(true);
        ...
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
});
```

Later still... Found a solution for the RadioButtonGroup as well:

To get that initial unselected state, add an invisible first listItem with null model:

```
myRbg.add(new qx.ui.form.RadioButton("").set({
     model: null, visibility: "excluded"
}));
```

Then add the same style of code as for the selectionBox to the form validator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this demo which offers exactly which your looking for in the SelectBox case:
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.1/demobrowser/index.html#data~Form.html

You can simply check for the selection in the validator.